# Why is it a Borel set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Claim: $\displaystyle \bigcup_{a,b \in \mathbb{Q}}[a,b)$ is a Borel set.
 
Solution: I arrive at $[a,b)=\displaystyle \bigcap_{a,b \in \mathbb{Q}}(a-\frac{1}{n},b)$. This means that $[a,b)$ is a countable intersection of open sets. Also, 
$\displaystyle \bigcup_{a,b \in \mathbb{Q}}[a,b)=\displaystyle \bigcup_{a,b \in \mathbb{Q}} \left(\displaystyle \bigcap_{a,b \in \mathbb{Q}}(a-\frac{1}{n},b)\right)$.

> My question is: out of these arguments, can we say that $\displaystyle \bigcup_{a,b \in \mathbb{Q}}[a,b)$ is a Borel set? How?
>   Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, $\bigcup_{a,b \in \mathbb{Q}}[a,b)$ is the whole real line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first argument is a little flawed: I take it that you meant
$$
[a,b)=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(a-\frac{1}{n},b\right)
$$
which shows that $[a,b)$ is a countable intersection of open sets and hence it is an element of the Borel $\sigma$-field (i.e. is a Borel set). Is this clear?

Now to show that 
$$
\bigcup_{a,b\in\mathbb Q}[a,b)
$$
you just have to note that it is a countable union of Borel sets and hence it is itself a Borel set. This is by the definition of a $\sigma$-field.

Comment: You are welcome.